# Expresso Store Get a Quote instead of payment

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using Expresso Store v2 for a rental service.
Is it possible when a client makes an order he gets a quote? I thought this was a feature but I can't find it.

Or is it possible to put an order on Pending by default? So stock levels will stay the same. I could hide the payment part for the client and it would function as a quote request.

Asking this, it comes to mind that there aren't any options for orders like refund, cancelled etc... I can create an Order state and name it Refund but this doesn't restore the stock levels, total sales etc. I could be wrong and missed something.

Tnx

[edit]
I solved it (sort of). Still would be nice as a feature.
I disabled track_stock but left the stock numbers intact. So now stock numbers al always maximum. Payment part is hidden and now clients can request a Quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track quotes, you can simply use the 'manual' payment method in Store, which will allow customers to proceed through the checkout without entering their card details etc.

This will still adjust stock levels, so as you found out, if you want to leave stock levels intact you will need to disable the "track stock" option for those products.

Store never adjusts stock levels after an order is complete (when you refund/delete the order etc). The reason for this is that life is often much more complicated (refunded items are faulty, or are still in transit back to your office etc), so we make no assumptions about your business processes. If you wish to restore stock levels for refunded items, this must be done manually.

Comment: Thanks. I asked this because Prestahop does restore stock levels and seems to work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it would be technically possible. I was referring more to the fact that in many cases a refunded item isn't immediately available for sale, so it doesn't always make sense to restore the stock levels. It could probably be made an option though.

Comment: Ah now I know what you meant. As an option it would be perfect. Then you could choose to restore stock levels if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I know of an add-on that's in development that may be helpful for you. Check out Michael Rog's [Expiring Carts](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-expiring-carts). Looks like he's got a private beta going on now.

Comment: Tnx Jeremy, sounds good. I will sign up for the beta.